# Multiple definition of ' ' first defined here error

Tags: c++

I have been getting the error when I use the code `$ g++ a.o b.o -o a` :

```
b.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `a'
a.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**NOTE:** b.cpp defines the variable int a

File a.cpp is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void func(); 
int a; 
int main(){
    func();
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And File b.cpp is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
void func(){
a = 100;
}
```

I tried making the int a in a.cpp extern by `extern int a;`
and even including `#include "b.cpp"` after function declaration but the error remains.

Please help me and provide some explanation why my approach is unsuccessful. 
Thank You

Comment: is there some other problem you are trying to solve? Just asking, because I dont see why you would need a global variable here (eg. simply making `func` return the value would "fix" your code)

Comment: How to fix it? All my approaches have been mentioned above.

Comment: fix it by eg not declaring the variable globally at all, but rewrite func to `int func() { return 100; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a variable twice, i.e. variable named `a` is defined in translation unit `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`. That's violating the one definition rule.

If you want to share a variable between different translation units, define it in one and just *declare* it in the other:

```
// a.cpp:
int a;
...

// b.cpp:
extern int a;
...
```

If you want, however, to have two variables with the same name or simply want to avoid unintended name clashes, use `static` to make "global" variables visible to the respective translation unit only, or introduce namespaces. Note that you then have *two* different variables, which do not share a common value.

Comment: Wouldn't using [extern int a] in a.cpp fix the error then?

Comment: Better yet, do not define non-const global variables.

Comment: But as the note suggest - b.cpp defines the variable a and not a.cpp so wouldn't it be [extern int a] in a.cpp and not b.cpp?

Comment: define it in either of the two, but be sure to define it only once.

Comment: Do double-check that you recompiled a.o; fixing your code does nothing if you forget to compile it into your new test executable.